# Fabric8 maven plugin fails on run build

Tags: java, docker, maven, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

I'm running mvn build and using `fabric8` maven plugin for dockerizing the application. Every time I run the build it fails as it uses a docker command that fails `docker-credential-secretservice version`. 
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0:build (docker-build) on project useradmin-server-war: Error getting the version of the configured credential helper: Process 'docker-credential-secretservice version' exited with status 1 -> [Help 1]`

I tried the command manually in the terminal but it fails and outputted: `unknown credential action version`
 
Any ideas how to solve this, I can't find something useful when I searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and resolved in later versions of the plugin. I changed the plugin version from `0.28.0` to `0.33.0`.
Here's the plugin from the `pom.xml` (after updating the version):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.33.0</version>
</plugin>
```